# How can I add one OPENGL page to another when ENTER key is pressed?

Tags: opengl, glut

I created one GLUT project which has my project's introduction page. When I pressed ENTER key, it should redirect to my front page of project which I created as another project.

Answer (score 0):

With glutKeyboardFunc() we can detect keystrokes and do a system call to start the program.

```
void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y) {
    if (c == 13) {
        system("C:\\Users\\Folder\\program.exe");
        exit(0);
    }
}

glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
```